# Error "field \"insert_users\" not found in type: 'mutation_root'" en Hasura Actions

Tags: nodejs

tengo una duda, al utilizar actions con Hasura me sale este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya tengo todo configurado y la mutación la probé antes de convertirla a actions, les muestro también mi código:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si pueden ayudarme o darme algún apoyo se los agradecería :D

Comment: pareciera que `insert_users` no existe como mutación en tu server con Hasura. no será `insert_user`?

Comment: Por favor lee has el [tour] y lee [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes agregar el código como texto y no como imágen. La lectura no te tomará mas de 5 minutos. saludos

Comment: Hola @Japsz si lo tengo, es más, la action la hice directamente con graphiql integrado en Hasura ye hice una derive action para que funcionara todo correcto :c